# Powershell Script Wrapper for Running as Admin

Tags: powershell, group-policy

I am writing a script to deploy through group policy. The script deletes a number of registry settings to fix an issue we have on our build of Windows. The script needs to run as an administrator as the keys exist in hives that require admin rights to delete.

Because GP runs powershell scripts as the logged on user, I am looking at creating a wrapper which will read an encrypted password for the local user account and then run the script with it.

My script is able to read the credential, but I am getting errors when running the start-process command. If I try and reference the script it will give the error that the path doesn't exist, even though you can dump the contents using cat .

I then tried reading it into a variable and running powershell with the -command argument. If I do this I get an error.

"Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The parameter is incorrect"

I understand that I need to enclose the code in braces, but I am not sure how this is done as concatenating them to the string doesn't work.

```
if($connected) {
    $Encrypted = Get-Content <PATH TO PASSWORD FILE>
    $pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $Encrypted -Key (1..16)
    $user = <MY ADMIN ACCOUNT>
    $Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $user, $pass

    echo $(pwd)
    echo $(cat <PATH TO SCRIPT>)
    $code = $( cat <PATH TO SCRIPT> )
    #Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {$code} -Credential $Credential
    #Start-Process powershell.exe <PATH TO SCRIPT> -Credential $Credential 
    Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-command $code" -Credential $Credential 
}
```

I just need a way of executing the code in my second script, but I can't work out how to do this as it's not behaving as expected. Sorry, as I am sure I am missing something obvious.

Comment: Can't you simply drop the line `$code = $( cat <PATH TO SCRIPT> )` and use the `-FilePath` parameter? 
`Start-Process -FilePath "<PATH TO SCRIPT>" -Credential $Credential`

Comment: Thanks, I have got it to work with -ArgumentList "-file <PATH TO SCRIPT>".